# Printing errors during save custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to debug my save_post function and cannot get the $_POST array to print so that I can see what's being posted.  Please help!

```
add_action ('save_post', 'save_events');

function save_events($post_id){
    if (('event' == $_POST['post_type']) && ('publish' == $_POST['post_status']) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' )){ 
               print_r($_POST);

                       //function code...
            }
}
```

Comment: The same answer as here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131217/21376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a `die` after that `print_r()` or (better) use `error_log()` instead of `print_r()` and look at your php error logs for the output.

What's happening is WordPress is reloading content before you get a chance to see the output (in most cases).